# How to do it without the while loop in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this,

```
A         |        B
----------------------
1         |       10
1         |       20
2         |       30
2         |       40
```

I need output as,

```
A         |         B
------------------------
1         |        10,20
2         |        30,40
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: GROUP BY, and perhaps STUFF or GROUP_CONCAT or similar. Which data type for column B?

Comment: Its of int data type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
create table #table2(
    col1 int,
    col2 varchar(10),
)

insert into #table2
select 1, '10' union all
select 1, '20' union all
select 1, '30' union all
select 2, '40' union all
select 2, '50' union all
select 2, '60'


select
    col1,
    col2 = 
        stuff((
            select
                ', ' + t2.col2
            from #table2 t2
            where
                t2.col1 = t1.col1
            for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'
        ), 1, 2, '')
from #table2 t1
GROUP BY t1.col1
```

Comment: you don't really need a group by in your inner query in this example. you do need an order by

Comment: @ughai sorry. my mistake.not seen tag

Comment: I cant insert into another table like that because its having too many rows

Comment: @Giri Prasad : i haven't understood, explain briefly.

Comment: @Kumar I cant mention all the rows like you did in your answer coz my table is having many rows

Comment: @Giri Prasad : `create table #table2...` and `insert into #table2...` statements are not needed. Just replace the `table name` and `column name` in the query to your requirements and use only the query.